# Sitecore Homepage Shows Error Message, but is viewable at different URL

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

In my sitecore instance, (8.2 rev 170407), I'm having an issue viewing the homepage in both my dev enviroment and my staging server. Going to the homepage (the root of the server) redirects to this URL 
http://[website]/sitecore/service/nolayout.aspx?item=%2f&layout=%7b00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%7d&device=Default

The message says:

> The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) may have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Additional Information:
>
> Requested URL: /
>
> Requested Layout:  {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
>
> Requested Device:  Default

In testing this, I set the Home item to have an alias of /home, which I can visit and see the page looking fine.

This issue began when I set up Helix via the Yeoman script, and built it in VS2015. This is my first Sitecore Site so I handily accept that I made a mistake -- for example when I built the Solution for the first time it overwrote my Web.config. I had a backup of that Web.config and was able to bring the site back online but the Homepage has eluded me.

I've published, and republished. In my naive experience, I find it odd I can see the homepage at /home but not /.  Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Check your configuration from `http://yoursite/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` and check the `<sites>` entry. Ensure the values for `rootPath` and `startItem` are correct. For the default `website` entry is it : `rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home"`

Comment: Thank you, that wasn't quite the answer as it was the correct config information. But it lead me to look at some other config files where rootPath was pointing to a directory that didn't exist. It wasn't reflected in showconfig.aspx but nevertheless was overwriting it.